# android webview setbackground() doesn't work

Tags: android, webview, background-color

I have a web view on a picture and I want when I click on a button to change the background of the webview to transparent...

To do so I use webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

When I press the button my webview doesn't change it's color.. I have to write something in it to change it's color after I press the button..

Does somebody knows how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   WebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
   WebView.setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Update:: be sure to have Javascript enabled!

Comment: Do you have Javascript enabled?

Comment: I dont't think I have it.. I use sdk 2.2 and when I try to call the setJavaScriptEnabled(true), I get an error sayng that the method doesn't exist...

Comment: Be sure to add this after the html / data is loaded into the webview

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the following solution works on every droid I tested (2.1, 2.3, 3.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.1.1, 4.1.2):

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html><body background=\"#00000000\" link=\"white\"><font color=\"white\">" + content + "</font></body</html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
webview.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) // Android v3.0+
 try {
  Method method = View.class.getMethod("setLayerType", int.class, Paint.class);
  method.invoke(webview, 1, new Paint()); // 1 = LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE (API11)
 } catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebView.setBackgroundColor(#00000000);
It worked for me once. 
You can take help of this link [Click HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550700/how-to-get-transparent-background-of-webview-for-4-0-version)