# How to get transparent background of webView for 4.0 version

Tags: android, webview

I am looking for a piece of code which is able to get a transparent background in a `WebView` for version 4.0 and above. My code is working fine with version 2.3 but it is getting a white background when I run it on version 4.0 and 4.2. I am providing my code which is working for version 2.3, but not in 4.0 and 4.2. Please help me. Thanks in advance...

**In XML:**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:hardwareAccelerated ="true"        
    />
```

**In activity file:**

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
backButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
webView.setBackgroundColor(0);                      
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Info.html");
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);  
/* this is used to make the background white after loading the file on screen. */
```

Comment: I tried this once, but eventually I used the same background for WebView and the application, so there was an illusion that it was transparent.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

and remove `android:hardwareAccelerated ="true"`
as that is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks... Its working now. But it is usually work from the xml(I think).

Comment: @gunar: Yeah! I've already done it before few months. Can't upvote twice.

Comment: NOTE: setting the background seems to have to follow setting the URL.

Comment: this trick will **NOT** work with youtube movies. They wont play anymore because they need hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 11):

If webview is scrolable:

Add this to the Manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

OR

Add the following to WebView in the layout:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:layerType="software"
```

Add the following to the parents scroll view:

```
android:layerType="software"
```

Comment: settings android:hardwareAccelerated="false" This works for me .. on android 16 HCL device.. you can enable it on application and just disable it where you use activity that has webview ..

Answer (score 1):

setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
will make your webview transparent