# how to set newline for paragraph and background image webview in android values from xml using xmlparsing

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to set newline in web view in android side values from XML.I am using (/n) tags in XML but it not accepted.I don't know how make new line in paragraph and also i want to set background image in webview image from drawable folder...

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rsslistitemdesc);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    desc=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    itemdesc=getIntent().getExtras().getString("desc");          
    String htmlText = "%s ";
    String description = "<html><body>" + "<p align=\"justify\" >"+"<font color=\"black\"><br>"+ b.getString("desc")+ "<br/></p>" + "</body></html>";
    desc.loadData(String.format(htmlText, description), "text/html", "utf-8");
    desc.setBackgroundColor(0);
    desc.setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);     
}

    example.xml
    <item>
    <title></title>        
    <desc>A summary of your objectives,educational qualification,experience,skills    relevant to the field of work you are going to enter.Here you can detail down each.It highlights your accomplishments to show a potential employer that you are qualified for the work you want.Remember it is not a biography of everything you have done.Its core PURPOSE is to get you an interview.A resume can or should reflect more than just your education.As a fresher the experience lies in the projects,seminars,workshops etc. you pursue during your academics.Showcase your important details like extra – curricular,volunteer &amp; leadership experiences.Tailoring separate resumes to fit each career field in which you are job searching may be important.Some people create slightly different resumes tailored to each job opening.
    </desc>
    </item>
```

Comment: Show some code that you have tried so far.It would be easy to answer.

Comment: hi user2012 this code i have tried so far but values from xml that is a problem i don't know to how to make a newline in paragraph and in-between in paragraph and also i want to set background image from drawable folder

Answer (score 4):

You can use `"<br>"` tag to do the task.See the below example,

```
 desc=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.description);
String webdata="<html><body><p>To break lines<br>in a text,<br>use the br element./p</body</html>"
 desc.loadData(webdata, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

This will result the following output,

```
To break lines
in a text,
use the br element.
```

Comment: you are right but i get values from xml know than how can i use this <br> tag  String description = "<html><body>" + "<p align=\"justify\" >"+"<font color=\"black\"><br>"+ b.getString("desc")+ "<br/></p>" + "</body></html>";

Comment: See the answer of this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml

Comment: sorry user2012 i'm not getting values from string.xml i'm using xml parsing see the above xml file

Comment: If thats a static text then why dont you write it inside a String in the Java class.

Comment: Not a static text in future i want to update means xml parsing is comfortable know thats y.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
System.getProperty("line.separator") or "\n" for new line.
```

To set background,follow this link.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008225/android-webview-setbackground-doesnt-work)

Comment: hi sri but values from xml how can i make new line.I use this code b.getString("desc") means it get all the values from particular tag and displays in webview.so,how can i make a newline in-between in paragraph and background color also not set

Comment: Try this one ,myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); remove the setBackgroundResources() method. And you cant able to add break in the middle as you did.You have to get the string value in StringBuilder sb =b.getString("desc"); and you have to explicitly append the "<br />" tag where ever you want and then give it to html tag.

Comment: sorry sri i'm not getting values from string.xml i'm using xml parsing see the above xml file